# JavaScript UTC Date Comparison Bug

Tags: javascript, date

I'm comparing UTC dates and getting this very weird result.

`now` is definitely bigger than `start` as far as I can tell, yet the statement returns false.

```js
var start = new Date('2021-01-29T21:00:00.000Z');
var now   = new Date('2021-01-29T00:16:47.797Z');

console.log(now >= start); //false
```

The issue seems to be related to midnight (00), it seems to work fine for other times.

I did notice by the way that there's an existing stackoverflow issue with a pretty similar title, but the issue itself seems to be different.

Comment: Can you explain why you think that 0 hours "is definitely bigger than" 21 hours on the same day?

Comment: [_"most often midnight is considered the **start of a new day** and is associated with the hour 00:00"_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight#Start_and_end_of_day)

Comment: @meriton Yeah, lack of sleep. My bad.

Comment: You don't even need a Date object to do this comparison, you can do it with strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youre comparing 12:16:47 in the morning, or 45 minutes till 1am against 9pm in the same day. Chronologically this makes perfect sense. If you were to change "now" to the day after, referencing 12:16am of the following day, it returns true.

```js
var start = new Date('2021-01-29T21:00:00.000Z');
var now = new Date('2021-01-29T00:16:47.797Z');

console.log(now >= start); //false

var start = new Date('2021-01-29T21:00:00.000Z');
var now = new Date('2021-01-30T00:16:47.797Z');

console.log(now >= start); //true
```